# What would I need to do to refer to servers by name instead of by IP?

Tags: linux, networking

I'm not sure what's needed to ssh or connect to another computer by name instead of by IP. Do I have to host a local DNS server? Is it a router software rule I can add? I know I can add entries in my /etc/hosts file as IP aliases but I rather have it set for all machines as part of my networking setup.

Comment: In general name resolution is either in `/etc/hosts` or a DNS server.  Although there are also zeroconf solutions.

Comment: @StephenRauch: No broadcast-based name resolution like Windows?

Comment: zeroconf can do that.  Also know as bonjour for the apple lovers among us, and as avahi for those of the unix camp.

Comment: Quite a few home routers also act as a local DNS server. As you didn't tell us which router you use ...

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few ways to do this.

[mdns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) - what apple calls zeroconf is pretty commonly set up by default on many linux boxen, supported in OS X as bonjour, and linux as avahi. It does "blah.local" addresses.

If you're running samba, I believe [nmbd](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/nmbd.8.html) runs, allowing you to run "windows" network name resolution.

You *could* also run a local DNS server. Hostnames are at a higher level than "routing", though I suppose you do/can run a DNS server in the average consumer router.